# Mysql: In the world database how is the code if you want to see the largest city (chosen by population) in each continent?

Tags: mysql

has to show its country and the population as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This hack shows country as well as requested. ('World' is a mysql sample database).

```
select a.continent, co.name, c.name, c.population from city c, country co,
(select co.continent, max(ci.population) as m
from country co, city ci 
where co.code=ci.countrycode 
group by co.continent) a
where c.population=a.m and c.countrycode=co.code
```

Results in:

[image]